# Почему разнятся значения Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) в разных приложениях?

Tags: c#, .net

Я пишу сервис, где мне необходимо получить папку AppData\Roaming. Пользуюсь следующей конструкцией `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);`
Но получаю следующее значение: `C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\`
Но если я запускаю консольное приложение и проделываю все тоже самое - получаю правильный результат. Может кто-нибудь, пожалуйста, объяснить в чем дело. Бьюсь несколько часов над проблемой и не могу никак решить.

Comment: А ничего что папка AppData у каждого пользователя - своя?

Comment: @PavelMayorov а ничего, что в одном приложении одно значение, а в втором другое при одинаковом использовании одинаковых методов?

Comment: Это нормально когда они запускаются от имени разных пользователей.

Comment: @PavelMayorov тогда каким образом мне получить AppData\Roaming при запуске от NT AUTHORITY\СИСТЕМА?

Comment: @OlegLylok очевидно, что вам потребуется предоствать сервису данные о вашем пооьзователе, самый простой способ, запускать сервис от его имени

Comment: @OlegLylok так вы его получили же. Смотрите, в пути есть и AppData, и Roaming...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile` - это путь к профилю для пользователя SYSTEM. Если вам нужен профиль другого пользователя, запускайте сервис от его имени, или найдите путь для конкретного пользователя (у SYSTEM для этого достаточно прав). Это можно сделать как-то так:

1. Получить токен пользователя через [LogonUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/a6d880a0-0aed-4bdb-89c9-4f667ecb510e)
2. Загрузить его профиль через [LoadUserProfile](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/userenv/nf-userenv-loaduserprofilew)
3. Получить путь к нужной папке с помощью [SHGetKnownFolderPath](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath), передав ей полученный токен